# Number of neighbours KNN algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, knn

I applied the KNN algorithm in matlab for classifying handwritten digits. the digits are in vector format initially 8*8, and stretched to form a vector 1*64. So each time I am comparing the first digit with all the rest data set, (which is quite huge), then the second one with the rest of the set etc etc etc. Now my question is, isn't 1 neighbor the best choice always? Since I am using Euclidean Distance, (I pick the one that is closer) why should I also choose 2 or 3 more neighbors since I got the closest digit?

Thanks

Comment: Let's say you have one 7 which is wrongly written and looks exactly like the 1 you are checking now. You get the wrong result. Now, how likely is it that among 5 best matches, there are more 7s than 1s?

Comment: guys is it normal to get 90.21% success? on a 1593 digits data set?

Comment: @TestTest I'm not an expert on image recognition, I usually use ML for other purposes, but 90.2% sounds pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take noise into consideration. Assume that maybe some of your classified examples were classified wrongly, or maybe one of them is oddly very close to other examples - which are different, but it is actually only a "glitch".  In these cases - classifying according to this off the track example could lead to a mistake.

From personal experience, *usually* the best results are achieved for k=3/5/7, but it is instance dependent.

If you want to achieve best performance - you should use [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) top chose the optimal `k` for your specific instance.

Also, it is common to use only odd number as `k` for KNN, to avoid "draws"

Comment: guys is it normal to get 90.21% success? on a 1593 digits data set?

Answer (score 0):

**A simple program to demonstrate ML Knn algorithm**

Knn algorithm works by training a computer with set of data and passing inputs to get expected output. Ex:- consider a parent want to train his child to identify picture of "Rabbit", here parent will show n number of photos of a a Rabbit and if the photo belongs to Rabbit then we shout Rabbit else we will move on , like this in this approach a supervision is taken care to the computer by feeding set of data to get expected output

```
from sklearn.neigbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv("D:\\heart.csv")
new_data{"data":np.array(df[["age","gende","cp","trestbps","chol","fbs","restecg","thalach","exang","oldpeak","slope","ca","thal"]],ndmin=2),"target":np.array(df["target"]),"target_names":np.array(["No_problem","Problem"])}
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(new_data["data"],new_data["target"],random_state=0)
kn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
kn.fit(X_train,Y_train)
x_new=np.array([[71,0,0,112,149,0,1,125,0,1.6,1,0,2]])
res=kn.predict(x_new)
print("The predicted k value is : {}\n".format(res))
print("The predicted names is : {}\n".format(new_data["target_names"][res])
print("Score is : {:.2f}".format(kn.score(X_train,Y_train)))
```